# When you're sad and down, what do you say?

Tags: riddle

> Born to grumble, born to cry,
>
> Every day, at work or at school, you encounter me.
>
> Help does not come, you must suffer through my cause.
>
> Love and hate, they say are a pair, though I and happiness, are we not?

BIG HINT:

> I have shown the answer 2 times already, use the riddle to only confirm it.

Another hint:

> Meh, I'll add this later. Ugh, pls don't take this out.

The 3rd hint:

> Agh, the BIG HINT was supposed to to say THE ANSWER IS ON THE SCREEN NOT ONCE, BUT TWICE.

Comment: I hate to sound pedantic but should the title read 'For when *you're* sad and down' rather than *your*?

Comment: Something really mysterious: first letter of each line => BEHL => BLEH, which is OP's name... There's something fishy going on

Comment: @Menace If I were you, I'd put that in an answer

Comment: The fourth line makes me think of Cyanide.

Comment: Regarding the third hint, when you say 'the answer is on the screen'.  Is this true without rolling over to reveal any spoilers?

Comment: @BrentHackers See accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe it is

> Bleh

When you're sad and down, what do you say?

> Bleh : State of mind usually caused by boredom or a annoying situation that doesn't really causes any heavy emotional reactions, according to Google

Born to grumble, born to cry,

Every day, at work or at school, you encounter me.

Help does not come, you must suffer through my cause.

Love and hate, they say are a pair, though I and happiness, are we not?

> The word "bleh" fits well to all lines (bored at work or school, suffering of boredom when there is no help, boredom kinda opposite of happiness)

I have shown the answer 2 times already, use the riddle to only confirm it.

> OP's name is "bleh", and first letter of each line makes BEHL => BLEH

Comment: Oh my god, I finally succeeded to solve a puzzle, yay! :D

Comment: Bleh, huh? Ugh, this makes me sad. ;-) +1.

Answer (score 5):

It's

> Ugh.

I don't think that a line by line explanation is necessary, but the hint:

> I have shown the answer 2 times already, use the riddle to only confirm it.

points to

> ...thro**ugh** my cause. 
>  and 
>  ...tho**ugh** I and happiness...

And the last hint pretty much spells it out.

> **Ugh**, pls don't take this out.

Comment: What is your explanation for the last line of the riddle? (+1 for the rest!)

Comment: @paste Love : hate :: happiness : disgust. Also, there's an "ugh" there. :-) I don't think it gets much deeper than that. Am I missing something? Do you think I should add a line-by-line?

Comment: URGHHH WHY DO PPL TAKE MY CLUES THE WRONG WAY?!?!?!? (that's another hint)

Comment: You're closer than others though.

Comment: @MikeM. I'm satisfied, but you can never go wrong with a line-by-line.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> a comma.
>
> ```
> ,,
> ```
>
> A pair of commas (as seen above) looks a bit like a pair of crying eyes in some fonts.
>  Commas are encountered every day at school or work (assuming your work involves reading).
> I think the last two lines are another reference to the crying.
> Two commas appear in the title which fits the clue.

Comment: +1 This is actually very clever! But it doesn't just come from the title, and what about grumbling?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly too simple but maybe the question is:

> Why are you sad?

Answer (score 0):

> LOVE - Because 'love' is always the answer!
>
> You would (probably) encounter love every day so long as you leave the house (even if it isn't directed at you)
>
> Something about not being able to help who you love?  The cause is often a mysery.
>
> Love and Happiness could be said to be a pair

Comment: It was a long shot.  I just thought "Love and Happiness" would fit, and maybe 'every day you encounter me' - well you would even if it wasn't directed towards you.  I don't know...  Not my best guess.

Comment: You should explain how your  answer fits the riddle

Comment: Granted.  Best course now - remove the answer, or edit it with the best explanation I can muster?

Comment: You could try to edit with an anexplanation

Comment: Lesson learned.

Comment: The 4th clue is meant so that they are opposites, yet similar.